# Asymmetrical Armature Pose on Object with Mirror Modifier

Tags: modifiers, armature, mirror

I have an object with mirror modifier on the x axis and an armature consisting of properly named/parented bones for each side (ie: .R and .L on all bones accordingly). My problem is that when I connect the armature to the mirrored object it still affects both sides when posing.

I'm assuming it can be done, I seen a few people online discuss it, but following their techniques it doesn't seem to work for me. In case it matters at all I am on Blender 2.9 with rigify enabled.

Applying the mirror modifier first and then connecting the armature and object works how I want, albeit without the mirror. What I am trying:

- Create armature with left side bones and right side bones (named with .R and .L using auto naming)
- Apply the mirror
- Bind armature to object with automatic weights
- Edit the object and delete half of it on x
- Add new mirror modifier on x axis
- Move mirror above armature

That doesn't work, it seems that the unmirrored side still affects both sides and the mirrored sides weights aren't connected to the mesh anymore.

What am I missing? I spent many hours trying to figure this out and I am getting really frustrated.

Here is my blend file with the object and arm before applying anything.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M4_KewAkS0WfTxRA7cOmBzCGpfYIktT1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share your file at: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sure, but I wasn't sure what state it should be in as I wasn't sure if I am doing things right. So, rather than applying everything and having it further into problem, I shared the file of the object right before my listed steps above (so applying mirror, applying auto weight armature, cutting half of the object and adding a new mirror).
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M4_KewAkS0WfTxRA7cOmBzCGpfYIktT1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I saw _l and _r instead of .r and .l, may be each works, but the main problem is the symmetrical bones have to have identical names, for example Bone.002_l and Bone.002_r if the name not matches it won't work.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that, thank you! I'll give that a shot today and see how it goes. FYI the R and L are from the auto naming option, may be a function of rigify, not sure. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi again, I just wanted to post an update that naming the bones the same on both sides worked! All the stuff I was reading I don't think that was ever mentioned, but maybe I just missed it. Thanks again, much appreciated.